# Background image with button overtop

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some help with a td background, this HTML is for an email.

I'd like to set the image background and then apply a button over the top, in a certain location of the background image. Any guidance would be most appreciated!

Here is the TD:

```html
<table data-module="module-6" data-thumb="images/section3.png" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td data-bgcolor="bg-module" bgcolor="#eaeced">
      <table class="flexible" width="580" align="center" style="margin:0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td data-bgcolor="bg-block" class="holder" style="padding:10px 30px 20px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="170">
                    <tr>
                      <td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data- max="20" class="btn" align="center" style="font:bold 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding- alt:12px 20px; border-radius:0px;"
                        bgcolor="#e1e000">
                        <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#231f20; display:block; padding:12px 18px;" href="#">Play now</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Due to security risks, some E-mail providers will prompt the recipient to "download" the image to display it in the E-mail. Just a heads-up on that part. Also, from my own personal experience, I find more success in old-fashion HTML E-mails with inline CSS. No HTML5 or CSS3.

Comment: Thast correct, I simply need to display the image in the background of the TD and put the button over the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Add background="" and the background attributes in a style=""
Make sure there are no bgcolor in the tables below it or they were overwrite the bgimg.

Code attached.

```
<table data-module="module-6" data-thumb="images/section3.png" width="100%" 

cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://imageLink.jpg" bgcolor="#006554" width="640" align="center" valign="top" style="background-position:right top !important; background-size:cover !important;">
  <tr>
    <td data-bgcolor="bg-module" bgcolor="">




 <table class="flexible" width="580" align="center" style="margin:0 auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td data-bgcolor="bg-block" class="holder" style="padding:10px 30px 20px;" bgcolor="">

            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td align="center">
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="170">
                    <tr>
                      <td data-bgcolor="bg-button" data-size="size button" data-min="10" data- max="20" class="btn" align="center" style="font:bold 16px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#f9f9f9; text-transform:uppercase; mso-padding- alt:12px 20px; border-radius:0px;"
                        bgcolor="#e1e000">
                        <a target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#231f20; display:block; padding:12px 18px;" href="#">Play now</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="0"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```